# Where do I place custom PHP code (functions, classes) when creating a theme?

Tags: theming

WordPress has a place for it - functions.php, which is included automatically. Is there one for Drupal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The theme's template.php is used for logic and data processing. See the [Drupal theming guide](https://drupal.org/documentation/theme).

From the guide:

> For all the conditional logic and data
>   processing of the output, there is the
>   template.php file. It is not required,
>   but to keep the .tpl.php files tidy it
>   can be used to hold preprocessors for
>   generating variables before they are
>   merged with the markup inside .tpl.php
>   files. Custom functions, overriding
>   theme functions or any other
>   customization of the raw output should
>   also be done here. This file must
>   start with a PHP opening tag "`<?php`",
>   but the close tag is not needed and it
>   is recommended that you omit it.